# SQL: Creating table with Enum-like attribute that is one of only several types

Tags: sql, enums, attributes

Does SQL have an OR or `|` equivalent for attribute types that are only one of a few possibliities (ie Enum types)?

Example using my best guess for the `status` attribute in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Rental (
       status ("open" | "closed"),
       date datetime,
       id int PRIMARY KEY
)
```

I want status to be either "open" or "closed", nothing else. Is there syntax for this, or should I use `CHAR(6)` or should I use a constraint instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use check constraints when defining you table to narrow the domain of the attribute.

```
CREATE TABLE Rental (
       status char(6),
       date datetime,
       id int PRIMARY KEY
);

alter table Rental 
  add constraint status_valid_value
  check (status is null or (status in ('open','closed')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Rental (
       status char(6),
       date datetime,
       id int PRIMARY KEY
Check (status='open' OR status='closed')
)
```

It's also better to store status like int (1- open, 0 - closed, an so on)